# How can I hide the unused columns and rows of an Excel worksheet near cells with comments?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have some VBA code that queries and creates a table of data in a worksheet with comments in some of the cells.

It's occupies a range of about `A1:N200` and then I want to hide the unused space like in the code below.

```
Worksheet.Columns(Number_of_columns + 1).Resize(, Worksheet.Columns.Count - Number_of_columns).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Worksheet.Rows(Number_of_rows & ":" & Worksheet.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Doing so throws the run-time error 1004:

> Unable to set the hidden property of the range class

I have checked in a new Excel file, added a comment to the cell `A1` and then tried hidding the other columns and rows but had to leave 4 columns (A to D, but could have been for example A and C to E) and 5 rows visible. If I try hidding more I get the message `Cannot shift objects off sheet`.

Below is an example of a procedure that throws errors when ran in a new Excel file.

```
Private Sub Procedure()

  Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim Range As Excel.Range

  Set Worksheet = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  Set Range = Worksheet.Cells(1, 1)

  If Range.Comment Is Nothing Then
    Range.AddComment
  End If

  Set Range = Worksheet.Columns(2).Resize(, Worksheet.Columns.Count - 1).EntireColumn
  Range.Select ' Just to test the range, it works. Columns B to XFD
  Range.Hidden = True ' Throws error

  Set Range = Worksheet.Rows(2 & ":" & Worksheet.Rows.Count).EntireRow
  Range.Select ' Just to test the range, it works. Rows 2 to 1048576
  Range.Hidden = True ' Throws error

End Sub
```

Is there any way to hide them so that only the data is visible? The only workaround (not solution) that I can think of is removing the comments, hidding the columns and rows, and then adding the comments back, which is undesirable.

Comment: What are the values of `Number_of_columns` and `Number_of_rows`?

Comment: The first argument of `Resize` corresponds to rows, not columns btw.

Comment: Look at your quotes, you have Rows(1":"3), instead of Rows("1:3"), that will cause the 1004

Comment: @DarrellH - no, the quotes are correct - the result will be something like `200:1048576`.

Comment: @DarrellH I don't see what you mean. The line `Worksheet.Rows(Number_of_rows & ":" & Worksheet.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = True` is correct. It converts to something like this `Worksheet.Rows("201:1048576").EntireRow.Hidden = True`.

Comment: @BigBen @BigBen `Number_of_columns` and `Number_of_rows` are variables of the data type long which hold the size of the data table. You're correct, I did put the argument incorrectly in the question, my bad. I manually typed it and changed a little bit from the original code. I have edited the question and fixed it now.

Comment: My original question was what are their *values* when the error occurs, but I see you've addressed that in your edit.

Comment: BTW, what happens when you try to do this manually?

Comment: @BigBen I apologize for the misunderstanding. Their values are not fixed, it depends on the query. The date period picked before querying the data is what controls the amount of columns returned. The amount of rows are the number of employees related to that worksheet's company. For example in a query I just did `Number_of_columns` is 24 and `Number_of_rows` is 134. When I try to hide the columns and rows manually I also get the error. Have you gotten the error yourself? You should at least when trying the code example I added to the question.

Comment: What's the error message when you try to do it manually?

Comment: @BigBen I have opened a new Excel instance, manually inserted a comment on cell A1 and attempted to hide the columns B to the last one, XFD. [Screenshot of the error](https://i.imgur.com/LC2v319.png). It translates to "It is not possible to move objects off the sheet". The searchable English version should be the message "Cannot shift objects off sheet".

Comment: Oh - you had this detail in your question already (sorry, should have read more thoroughly). Yes, can reproduce the behavior. I personally would leave some extra blank columns/rows to the bottom/side to get around the issue, but I'm assuming that's not going to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, would be easier to see Excel, below is the sample code, just tested on Excel 2016:

```
Sub StackOverflow()

Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngLastColumn As Long
Dim lngLastColLetter As String
Dim shtWorking As Object

Set shtWorking = ActiveSheet
'find last row
lngLastRow = shtWorking.Cells(shtWorking.Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row + 1

'find last column
lngLastColumn = shtWorking.Cells(1, shtWorking.Columns.Count).End(-4159).Column + 1

'convert last column index to last column letter
lngLastColLetter = Split(shtWorking.Cells(1, lngLastColumn).Address, "$")(1)

'hide columns
shtWorking.Columns(lngLastColLetter & ":XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

'hide rows
shtWorking.Rows(lngLastRow & ":" & shtWorking.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = True

set shtWorking=nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: That code does not solve the issue. I commented cell A1, [ran it](https://i.imgur.com/pWcfEeK.png) and got [the error](https://i.imgur.com/C3ACsin.png) (message is in a different language).